# How to ignore lines in CSV file with a specific value?

Tags: csv

I am trying to read a CSV file and create a new one with a data of interest. There are rows in which specific data values (in age and gender columns) are marked as -1 and thus not needed in the new CSV table. Should I rewrite it using Pandas library? Moreover, I am trying to ignore the previous id (because some lines will be ignored) and have the new row count as the new id.

```
import csv

data = []

def transform_row(row):
    # id = new count
    age = line[2]
    gender = line[3]
    url = line[4]

    return [
    #new count
    age,
    gender,
    url
    ]

# read csv file line by line
with open('data_sample.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    """ bad try at ignoring the line with value -1
    for value in reader:
        if value == '-1':
            pass
        else:
            continue
    """

    # loop through each line in csv and transform
    for line in reader:
            data.append(transform_row(line))

# write a new csv file
with open('data_test.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    # define new csv writer
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')

    # write a header row to our output.csv file
    writer.writerow([
        #'id', - new line count as id
        'age',
        'gender',
        'url'
    ])

    # write our data to the file
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Also any other recommendations are welcome.

Comment: See https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_dropping_column_and_rows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the script via Pandas. Here are two solutions to the problem.

```
import pandas as pd

cols = [2, 3, 4]
data = pd.read_csv('data_sample.csv', usecols=cols, header=None)    
data.columns = ["url", "gender", "age"]

#remove the unneeded columns
data = data[data['gender'] != -1]  
data = data[data['age'] != -1]

#reset the index
data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

""" Additional working solution 
indexGender = data[data['gender'] == -1].index 
indexAge = data[data['age'] == -1].index

# Delete the rows indexes from dataFrame 
data.drop(indexGender,inplace=True) 
data.drop(indexAge, inplace=True)
"""
data.to_csv('data_test.csv')
```

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas` would make your life much easier, as the `csv` module is not great for granular data manipulation. If you wanted to drop rows based on the value of a particular column, you could initialize the original csv as a dataframe and create a new one with only the values you want:

```
import pandas as pd

start_data = pd.read_csv('./data_sample.csv')
# replace 'age' with 'gender' if that's what you prefer
clean_data = start_data[start_data['age'] != -1]
```

Checking the length of `start_data` and `clean_data` should show that all the unwanted rows have been removed. You could then create your new csv with:

```
clean_data.to_csv('./data_test.csv')
```